# Software update, requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources

Tags: update-manager

I'm quite new to Ubuntu and lately I've been struggling with software updater.

It lists the software to update but when I try to update gives the message

```
Requires installation of untrusted packages
This requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources.
```

[image]

I tried to execute `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` but the software updater continues listing software outdated.

Any help would be welcomed.